# Pass Response from Server Side GET request to client using Node.js

Tags: javascript, api

I have a button on a web page. When the button is clicked server side code sends a GET request to an internal API. I am having trouble passing the response back to the client. I can log the response in Node - but the response is empty on the client. Any help would be appreciated.

Client Side

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed')
  let body = document.querySelector('body')
  let h3 = document.createElement('h3')
  h3.innerText = 'ONT is on Node:'
  body.appendChild(h3)
  let button = document.createElement('button')
  button.innerText = 'Get ONT'
  body.append(button)
  button.addEventListener('click', getONT)

  async function getONT() {
    let response = await (fetch('https://ont.xxx.net/node/', ))
    .then(result => resultBody = JSON.stringify(result))
    .then(result => {console.log(resultBody)})
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  }
})
```

Server Side

```
#!/usr/bin/env nodejs
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https')
var fetch = require('node-fetch')

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  response.writeHead(200);
  response.end(JSON.stringify(getData()))
}).listen(8080);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');

async function getData() {
  const smx = "https://xxx/rest/v1/ont/searchall?filter=object.ontId LIKE xxx"
  console.log(smx)
  let response = await fetch(smx, {
    method: 'GET',
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Basic xxx",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    redirect: 'follow'
  })
  let data = await response.json()
  data = JSON.stringify(data)
  console.log(typeof(data))
  return data
}
```

Comment: are you getting anything written to the console log on the client side?  I ask because it looks like you're mixing away and .then code for promises on the client, and I think incorrectly.

Comment: All I get back is {}

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any response back from the server. If you want to send something back to the user you need to do a

```
 res.json({your json data});
```

This will return a JSON response to the request, further to that you can set the response code etc.

Comment: The server side code does get a response from the API it is calling. I can log the output of the API's response in node.js, I just cant figure out how to take the results of the function on the server side and send it back to the client. I have this on line 28 of the server side code: let data = await response.json()

Comment: Yah, but you are not sending the response back.. a simple return in your function is not going to return the data back to the client. res.json will send a response back to the request, hence the res.json, further to that though is the server side code the route too or just the main node js file?

Comment: server side code is what is making a GET request to an internal API. The client side code is what generates the web page with a simple button to call the server side code when clicked. I see your point about the response now.. But where do I put res.json()? http.createServer is sending a response to the client - but just for the initial fetch request. the response from the API that getData() calls returns a response. I'm just unsure of how to get that request back to the client. or maybe im going about this all wrong.

Comment: I think you have this setup wrong then.. So createServer is creating the node 'server' now you typically would create 'Routes' to run specific code blocks depending on what route a user put in, however if all you want is the entire node server to only call the api code then this could work, so where you have  response.end(JSON.stringify(getData())) try changing that to response.json(getData()), however this may be empty because getData may take longer to run. A better model would be to create routes

Comment: I switched to express and went with the route option like you suggested. Thanks for the point in the right direction. All is working well now.

Answer (score 0):

I went the route direction suggested by proxim0.

Server Side

```
app.use('/', router);

router.get('/' , function(req,res,next){
  request({
    method: 'GET',
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "xxx",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    redirect: 'follow',

    uri:'https://xxx:18443/rest/v1/ont/searchall?filter=object.ontId LIKE xxxxx'
  }).pipe(res)
})

// Server setup
app.listen(8080 , ()=>{
  console.log("server running");
});
```

Client Side

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed')
  let body = document.querySelector('body')
  let h2 = document.createElement('h2')
  h2.innerHTML
  let h3 = document.createElement('h3')
  h3.innerText = 'ONT is on Node:'
  body.appendChild(h3)
  let button = document.createElement('button')
  button.innerText = 'Get ONT'
  body.append(button)
  button.addEventListener('click', getONT)

  async function getONT() {
    let response = await fetch('https://ont.xxx/node/')
    let data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
    
  }
})
```

This allows me to get the data obtained in the server side code into the browser console of the client.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!